# sequelize-typescript: Common Method for get() in a model

Tags: node.js, typescript, model, sequelize.js

I have some get() function defined for START_DATE, END_DATE, MEET_START_DATE, MEET_END_DATE. If you will look closely at the get() functions defined for these column they are very similar . So i was trying to define a common function for all these get() functions. A function similar to getDay() defined at the end. But i am not able to call getDay() from with in the get() method. I dont have access to it .
**How to call getDay() from the get() function or something similar to it?** I also need to pass the parameters so that i have access to field name and the instance.

```
import {Table, Column, Model, DataType} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    schema: 'TEST',
    tableName: 'Person'
})
export class Person extends Model<Person> {
    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, primaryKey: true })
    ID: string;
    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    NAME: string;      
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){
            let value : Date = this.getDataValue('START_DATE');
            return value.getDay();
        }})
    START_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){
            let value : Date = this.getDataValue('END_DATE');
            return value.getDay();
        }})
    END_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){
            let value : Date = this.getDataValue('MEET_START_DATE');
            return value.getDay();
        }})
    MEET_START_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){
            let value : Date = this.getDataValue('MEET_END_DATE');
            return value.getDay();

            }})
    MEET_END_DATE: Date;


     getDay(field,instance) {
        let value : Date = instance.getDataValue(field);
        return value.getDay();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to define your common function outside the `Person` class:

```
import {Table, Column, Model, DataType} from 'sequelize-typescript';

function getDayOfField(field: string, instance: Model<any>) {
    let value : Date = instance.getDataValue(field);
    return value.getDay();
}

@Table({
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    schema: 'TEST',
    tableName: 'Person'
})
export class Person extends Model<Person> {
    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, primaryKey: true })
    ID: string;
    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    NAME: string;      
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){ return getDayOfField('START_DATE', this); }})
    START_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){ return getDayOfField('END_DATE', this); }})
    END_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){ return getDayOfField('MEET_START_DATE', this); }})
    MEET_START_DATE: Date;
    @Column({type:DataType.DATEONLY,
        get(){ return getDayOfField('MEET_END_DATE', this); }})
    MEET_END_DATE: Date;
}
```

(Defining and calling it as a static method of `Person` would be about the same.)  If you really want to make it an instance method, you can try casting `this` to `Person` inside your `get` implementations, which might work depending on what sequelize does at runtime (I'm not familiar with it).